# How to display or append several files in a terminal using shell script?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I would like to display several files one after another in a terminal, for instance, all the files of type `.java` in the current folder. Does anyone know how to do that by a line of shell? I guess probably we need to use `cat` and a variable...

Also, if possible, I would like to add the name of the files... For instance, the final layout in the terminal would be

```
p1.java
... 
contents of p1.java 
...  

p2.java
... 
contents of p2.java 
...
```

Does anyone know how to do it? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be as simple as:

```
$ cat *.java
```

If you want to display the filename before each listing, just use a loop:

```
$ for fn in *.java; do echo $fn; cat $fn; done
```

---

Just to enrich this answer a little bit: If you browse source code in your terminal regularly, you can get the content syntax highlighted as well via [pygments](http://pygments.org/). I use the following tiny function in my bashrc.

```
function pless() {
    type -P pygmentize &> /dev/null || { 
        echo "pygmentize required but not installed. Aborting." >&2; return 1; 
    }
    pygmentize "$@" | less -r 
}
```

Here's an example screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what if I want to add the name of the files between their contents, as described in my initial post?

Comment: When using `$@` you almost always want to quote it: `"$@"` -- then arguments with whitespace will be properly handled.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: `cat file1 && cat file2`

Or, alternatively: `cat dir/*`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what if I want to add the name of the files between their contents, as described in my initial post?

Comment: actually `cat file1 file2 file3`

Answer (score 0):

Use this shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh

for filename in `find /path_to_file -maxdepth 1 -name "*.java"`
do
        cat $filename
done
```

What is the use of `find` command is, you can specify 'maxdepth'. You can go into the deeper of the current folder and read .java files.